# Error creating view

Tags: sql, view

I have table `t1(name,phone,adress)` and want to create view `vw_1`. I'm looking for the basic logic to be something like:-

```
create view vw_1 (col1,col2)
as
if(t1.name is null)then 
select adress,phone from t1
else
select name,phone from t1
```

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Use the [coalesce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms190349.aspx) function (doc is for SQL Server, but it's a classic ANSI operator, and works in all -known by me- DBMS).

```
create view vw_1 (col1,col2)
    as
    select coalesce(name, adress), phone 
    from t1
```

if you mean "NULL OR EMPTY" then

```
CREATE VIEW vw_1(col1, col2)
  AS
  SELECT CASE WHEN COALESCE(name, '') = '' THEN adress else name END,
  phone
  FROM t1
```

see [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/50adb/2)

Comment: sorry, i need logic which looks like 
if(t1.name='')then
select adres,phone from t1
else
select name,phone from t1

//Big big sorry

Comment: you mean not "null" but "empty" ?

Comment: @user2033841 then you may try second solution.

Comment: I am try this

//Insert Data
 insert into t4 values
 ('','123','adres1'),
 ('name1','456','adres2'),
 ('name2','789',''),
 ('name3','135','adres3'),
 ('','246','adres4')
 ('','159','adres5')

//Create View
 CREATE VIEW vw_test(col1, col2)
  AS
  SELECT CASE WHEN COALESCE(name, '') = '' THEN name else adres END,
  phone
  FROM t4

//Select From View
select * from vw_test

//Result
''               123
adres2       456
''               789
adres3       135
''               246
''               159

Comment: @user2033841 oh sorry, I used the wrong order in my case when ;) Could you retry ?

Comment: sorry but i dont understand :)

Comment: @user2033841 I made an error (putting THEN name else adress instead of THEN adress else name). So I corrected, and you can retry ;)

Comment: It is Working,  thanks very much, can you tell me tutorial abaut programming in sql

Comment: @user2033841 well, I must admit I ain't got any nice reference... Try to google, you will find tons, some of them must be fine...